# Should I JSONB or JOIN Table for Logging User Actions and Notes in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am designing a DB where for multiple areas I want to keep track of User Actions and Notes.

Example of logging:

```
Sally edited this note at 11:34 on 11/25/2019
Matt changed note status from 'incomplete' to 'complete' at 13:57 on 12/15/2019
```

Example of Notes:

```
This customer is difficult to work with. - Matt 14:32 12/17/2019
Called customer, they told me they have a dog named George - Matt 18:32 12/17/2019
```

My application code will format and parse the data to the structure, no issue on how to do that.

My question is would this be best off using separate tables for each table for notes and logs.

I'll have many tables that you can imagine will need both. Vendors/Contacts/Customers that other users need to be able to make notes about.

Would this be best stored as JSON in say the `customers` Table, where each user action goes under the action JSON object, and I essentially make an ever-expanding array? `customers.notes` would be like

```
"notes": [{
  {
    "user": "Matt",
    "timestamp": "2019-04-21T16:18:18+00:00"
    "note": "Customer has a dog named fluffy"
  },
  {
    "user": "Sally",
    "timestamp": "2019-05-28T9:11:56+00:00"
    "note": "Called them just now"
  }
]
```

Or would this cause performance issues and I should create a JOIN Table and a `customers_note` and `customer_log` table, and similar for other tables like contacts, vendors, etc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What RDBMS do best is to store well-structured data in tables. No-SQL stuff like `jsonb` fields must be used when the data you are dealing with are only semi-strucutured, that is, when their structure differs from record to record. A typical example are ”additional info” fields in some databases, where each record has a different set of additional info items. (SQL purists would say that such databases are badly designed.)

This is not your case.

Each note consists of an operator id, a timestamp and a small text. Add two more fields (a `note_id` auto-incrementing primary key and the `customer_id` foreign key to be joined on) and you have an efficient `notes` table. Answering all kinds of questions (e.g. “is operator X biased towards certain classes of customers?”) will be easier with it than with those json arrays stuffed into the customers table and difficult to work with.

If your application really prefers json arrays instead of recordsets for notes, you can have PostgreSQL answer in json anyway with `json_agg(row_to_json(...))`.

As to performance, you are telling us too little to evaluate its issues properly: how many notes will there be for a customer? How often will they be needed? Will very old notes be really relevant in a current interaction? These are all aspects to be taken into consideration when evaluating performance.

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of "intrinsically heterogeneous"?

Comment: I have edited my answer, deleting that unclear expression and hopefully explaining myself better.